# arguments to super

Tags: ruby

I have a method that calls the base implementation:

```
class B
  def m x, y
    x + y
  end
end

class C < B
  def m x, y
    super * 10
  end
end
```

since I never refer to the parameters inside my derived method, is there a way to avoid using parameter names in `C.m`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* this is the closest you'll be able to come:

```
class B
  def m x, y
    x + y
  end
end

class C < B
  def m *args
    super * 10
  end
end

=> C.new.m 10, 10 # 200
=> C.new.m 1, 2, 3 # ArgumentError
```

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. in addition, you can omit the *args when you call super.

Comment: There's no need to name the parameters if you don't use them. `def m(*)` is sufficient.